# 'TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String' error

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, step

The following code is returning the error `(TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String)` at the last line:

```
And(/^the user makes the following changes in the response file "(.*)" and creates a uri with "(.*)" and wskey:$/) do |readFile, strURI,table|

  strRequestBody = $objFileIO.ReadFile(STR_FILE_SPEC + '/response/' + readFile)
  table.hashes.each do |rows|
    @request_uri = strRequestBody.gsub!(/#{rows[:parameter_in_response]}/, rows[:replace_with])
  end

  puts "this is url" + @request_uri   
end
```

Comment: `@request_uri` is nil which cannot be converted to a string and concatenated with `"this is url"`. It could be the scope as `@request_uri` is only defined inside a loop. If you mean to show each uri then it would need to be inside the block also.

Comment: @ TomDunning, Thank You Tom... how do I get the value of @request_uri out of the loop ?

Comment: Simply define it outside the loop.  Then the scoop will change.

Comment: @tukan it worked Thank You

Comment: @user3854376 you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it outside the loop, then the scoop will change.